# How to use cell indices instead of letters reading an excel in Matlab

Tags: excel, matlab

The use of readcell in MATLAB is as shown below (Matlab help)

```
M = readcell('airlinesmall_subset.xlsx','Sheet','2007','Range','G2:I11')
```

Is there a way to specify the range using numbers for columns rather than letters?

Comment: Where is that function defined? In the documentation? Seeing the function `readcell` would help.

Comment: Reading the [doc](https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readcell.html), it looks like `Rectangular Range: 'Corner1:Corner2' or [r1 c1 r2 c2]` is valid syntax. What happens if you use `...'Range', [2 7 11 9])` ?

Answer (score 0):

A bit further down in the documentation you linked to, you'll find this:

> Specify the exact range to read using the rectangular range in one of
> these forms.
>
> `'Corner1:Corner2'` — Specify the range using `Corner1` and `Corner2` which
> are the two opposing corners that define the region to read in Excel
> A1 notation. For example, `'C2:N15'`.
>
> `[r1 c1 r2 c2]` — Specify the range using a four element numeric vector
> containing start-row, start-column, end-row, and end-column. For
> example, `[2 3 15 13]`.